# CAS 3.5 not returning additional attributes

Tags: php, attributes, cas

I have CAS 3.5 server and have modified deployerConfigContext.xml and casServiceValidationSuccess.jsp as per this link =>  [LINK](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Attributes).  In the CAS Debug log, I can see that the additional attributes map is getting created there and the attributes values are also being logged.

```
2012-10-21 18:29:34,556 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.FastBindLdapAuthenticationHandler] - <Performing LDAP bind with credential: CN=mich@mycomp.com,CN=Users,DC=mygroup,DC=local>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,557 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.adaptors.ldap.FastBindLdapAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated [username: mich@mycomp.com]>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,560 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver] - <Attempting to resolve a principal...>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,561 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver] - <Creating SimplePrincipal for [mich@mycomp.com]>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,562 DEBUG [org.jasig.services.persondir.support.ldap.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Created seed map='{username=[mich@mycomp.com]}' for uid='mich@mycomp.com'>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,564 DEBUG [org.jasig.services.persondir.support.ldap.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Adding attribute 'cn' with value '[mich@mycomp.com]' to query builder 'null'>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,565 DEBUG [org.jasig.services.persondir.support.ldap.LdapPersonAttributeDao] - <Generated query builder '(cn=mich@mycomp.com)' from query Map {username=[mich@mycomp.com]}.>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,678 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <Resolved principal mich@mycomp.com>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,678 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <Principal found: mich@mycomp.com>
2012-10-21 18:29:34,681 DEBUG [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <Attribute map for mich@mycomp.com: {Name=mich@mycomp.com, mem=[CN=WFC,OU=Applications,DC=mygroup,DC=local, CN=User Management,OU=Applications,DC=mygroup,DC=local, CN=Wshop,OU=Applications,DC=mygroup,DC=local], dName=Scott}>
```

But, when I access the "attributes" array from my PHP CAS Client, it returns a blank array.

```
<?php print_r(phpCAS::getAttributes());?>
```

gives a blank array. If I hard code any thing in the casServiceValidationSuccess.jsp, it shows the attribute in the array, but value is null.

```
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
    <!-- Begin Ldap Attributes -->
    <c:if test="${fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications) > 0}">
    <cas:attributes>
    <cas:mem>${fn:escapeXml(assertion.chainedAuthentications[fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications)-1].principal.attributes.mem)}</cas:mem>
    </cas:attributes>
...
...
```

Am i missing anything ???

Comment: I read somewhere that the service URL ( the URL I am trying to protect with CAS ) must be on SSL and should have valid certificate, only then, CAS will return the attribute map in the callback response .. is that true ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on [CAS issue 655](https://issues.jasig.org/browse/CAS-655). Here is what my casServiceValidationSuccess.jsp ended up looking like:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<cas:serviceResponse xmlns:cas='http://www.yale.edu/tp/cas'>
    <cas:authenticationSuccess>
        <cas:user>${fn:escapeXml(assertion.chainedAuthentications[fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications)-1].principal.id)}</cas:user>

    <%-- Added attributes in response--%>
    <cas:attributes>
      <c:forEach var="attr"
                 items="${assertion.chainedAuthentications[fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications)-1].principal.attributes}"
                 varStatus="loopStatus" begin="0"
                 end="${fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications[fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications)-1].principal.attributes)-1}"
                 step="1">
        <%-- Produce output exactly as CAS client code expects it: <cas:attrName>attrValue</cas:attrName> --%>
        <cas:${fn:escapeXml(attr.key)}>${fn:escapeXml(attr.value)}</cas:${fn:escapeXml(attr.key)}>
      </c:forEach>
    </cas:attributes>
<c:if test="${not empty pgtIou}">
        <cas:proxyGrantingTicket>${pgtIou}</cas:proxyGrantingTicket>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications) > 1}">
        <cas:proxies>
<c:forEach var="proxy" items="${assertion.chainedAuthentications}" varStatus="loopStatus" begin="0" end="${fn:length(assertion.chainedAuthentications)-2}" step="1">
            <cas:proxy>${fn:escapeXml(proxy.principal.id)}</cas:proxy>
</c:forEach>
        </cas:proxies>
</c:if>
    </cas:authenticationSuccess>
</cas:serviceResponse>
```